# Capitalization after a colon

Tags: puntuación, uso-de-mayúsculas

In English, one can connect two sentences with a colon.  There can be a capital letter after the colon.

If I'm understanding the rules correctly, that capital letter after the colon is not possible.  Did I understand correctly?

Example in English:

> Flor is happy: She made her deadline.

Does it have to look like this in Spanish?

> Flor está contenta: logró entregar el proyecto a tiempo.

Or can I use a capital L in *logró*?

Comment: I didn't know that was correct english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to RAE capitals should follow the colon [only in certain cases](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp) (see section 3.3)

> - In the salutation when writing a letter.
> - In certain documents, after the verb that "explains" the nature of the document (for example, a certification).
> - When reproducing a textual quote.

Check [this section about capitals](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=2a3yRXFBiD6rvDOMtq) for more about when to use them. As you can see only sections 1.3, 1.4 and 1.6 are related to capitals after colon (the above examples).

When you have a cause-effect, or two sentences related without any other connector (see section 1.8) or an exemplification (see 1.5) you don't use capitals. To use their same examples:

> *Ya lo dijo Ortega y Gasset: «La claridad es la cortesía del filósofo».* (This is a quote.)
>
> *Se ha quedado sin trabajo: no podrá ir de vacaciones este verano.* (This is cause and effect.)
>
> *De vez en cuando tiene algunos comportamientos inexplicables: hoy ha venido a la oficina en zapatillas.* (This explains the first clause.)

I think your example falls in the category described by section 1.8 "oraciones relacionadas entre sí sin necesidad de emplear otro nexo" so you don't start with capital after the colon.